# Haskell - Error when handling the list's out of range on custom atIndex function

Tags: haskell

I started Haskell 1 day ago and I was trying to make some examples. I had a problem that I couldn't able to fix.


The problem is my `if` comparison not working. Program just igrones that stament and keep executing `else` statement. (Noted on code as comment)

Code:

```
lengthOf :: Num t => [t] -> t
lengthOf []  = 0
lengthOf arr = lengthOfAcc arr 1
    where
        lengthOfAcc :: Num t => [t] -> t -> t
        lengthOfAcc (_:t) counter = 
            if null t
                then counter
            else
                lengthOfAcc t (counter + 1)

atIndex :: (Ord t, Num t) => [t] -> t -> t
atIndex [] _      = error "atIndex: Empty list passed!"
atIndex arr index =
    if index < 0
        then error "atIndex: Index cannot be smaller than 0!"
    else
        atIndexAcc arr index 0 (lengthOf arr)

    where
        atIndexAcc :: (Ord t, Eq t, Num t) => [t] -> t -> t -> t -> t
        atIndexAcc (h:t) index counter arr_size = 
            if counter == index
                then h
            else
                if counter > arr_size -- This is not working. I don't know why.
                    then error "atIndexAcc: Out of array range!"
                else
                    atIndexAcc t index (counter + 1) arr_size
```

Console Output:

```
*EB_Functions> lengthOf [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
5
*EB_Functions> atIndex [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] 1
10
*EB_Functions> atIndex [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] 3
20
*EB_Functions> atIndex [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] 7
*** Exception: EB_Quick_F.hs:(71,9)-(78,61): Non-exhaustive patterns in function atIndexAcc
```

As you can see. What should I do for able to execute that line when `counter` exceeds
the `arr_size`. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are indeed using non-exhaustive patterns in your functions. Turn on warnings (strongly recommended!), and GHC will tell you which functions need to be defined in more cases. Basically, it will point out that you consider the case `(_:_)` (non empty list) but you forgot the case `[]` (empty list).

Comment: Oh, I just opened warnings and It's too helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what this expands to.

```
atIndex [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] 7
atIndexAcc [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] 7 0 (lengthOf [5, 10, 15, 20, 25])
-- counter is strictly evaluated for both index and arr_size checks
-- arr_size is evaluated to perform counter > arr_size check
atIndexAcc [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] 7 0 5
atIndexAcc [10, 15, 20, 25] 7 1 5
atIndexAcc [15, 20, 25] 7 2 5
atIndexAcc [20, 25] 7 3 5
atIndexAcc [25] 7 4 5
atIndexAcc [] 7 5 5
```

And that's when it stops - because `[]` doesn't match `(h:t)`, you get non-exhaustive patterns. You need a version of `atIndexAcc` that can accept the empty list. Note that you compared `counter > arr_size`, which also cannot happen because you're traversing the list as you count up; they're equal only when the list is exhausted.

Also, taking the length of the list means traversing the entire list; this isn't necessary to index it, and will force the whole list to exist in memory. That doesn't work with infinite lists, which are possible due to Haskell's lazy evaluation.